# Errors while installing react native packages using yarn

Tags: react-native, yarn-workspaces

Can someone help me with these errors while installing the packages using yarn.

I am using react native in the frontend and Django in the backend and for the database Postgres. I am running on WSL2 too and using node v16.13.1.

What can be the problem causing all of these errors?
Here are the errors in WSL

```
 Error running install script for optional dependency: "/mnt/e/myProjects/LastVersion/Project/node_modules/sqlite3: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
Arguments:
Directory: /mnt/e/myProjects/LastVersion/Project/node_modules/sqlite3
Output:
node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.11.0
node-pre-gyp info using node@16.13.1 | linux | x64
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp info check checked for \"/mnt/e/myProjects/LastVersion/Project/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v93-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node\" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v93-linux-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 403 https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v93-linux-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v93-linux-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@4.2.0 and node@16.13.1 (node-v93 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp http 403 status code downloading tarball https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v93-linux-x64.tar.gz
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.1.1
gyp info using node@16.13.1 | linux | x64
gyp info ok
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.1.1
gyp info using node@16.13.1 | linux | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.10 found at \"/usr/bin/python3\"
(node:25437) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/mnt/e/myProjects/LastVersion/Project/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/mnt/e/myProjects/LastVersion/Project/node_modules/sqlite3/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/mnt/e/myProjects/LastVersion/Project/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.1',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/mnt/e/myProjects/LastVersion/Project/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.1/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/mnt/e/myProjects/LastVersion/Project/node_modules/sqlite3',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info ok
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.1.1
gyp info using node@16.13.1 | linux | x64
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
gyp ERR! stack     at getNotFoundError (/mnt/e/myProjects/LastVersion/Project/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/mnt/e/myProjects/LastVersion/Project/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/mnt/e/myProjects/LastVersion/Project/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /mnt/e/myProjects/LastVersion/Project/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp ERR! stack     at /mnt/e/myProjects/LastVersion/Project/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp ERR! stack     at /mnt/e/myProjects/LastVersion/Project/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2
gyp ERR! command \"/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/bin/node\" \"/mnt/e/myProjects/LastVersion/Project/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js\" \"build\" \"--fallback-to-build\" \"--module=/mnt/e/myProjects/LastVersion/Project/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v93-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node\" \"--module_name=node_sqlite3\" \"--module_path=/mnt/e/myProjects/LastVersion/Project/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v93-linux-x64\" \"--napi_version=8\" \"--node_abi_napi=napi\" \"--napi_build_version=0\" \"--node_napi_label=node-v93\"
gyp ERR! cwd /mnt/e/myProjects/LastVersion/Project/node_modules/sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.1
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/bin/node /mnt/e/myProjects/LastVersion/Project/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/mnt/e/myProjects/LastVersion/Project/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v93-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/mnt/e/myProjects/LastVersion/Project/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v93-linux-x64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/mnt/e/myProjects/LastVersion/Project/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2
node-pre-gyp ERR! command \"/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/bin/node\" \"/mnt/e/myProjects/LastVersion/Project/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp\" \"install\" \"--fallback-to-build\"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /mnt/e/myProjects/LastVersion/Project/node_modules/sqlite3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute '/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/bin/node /mnt/e/myProjects/LastVersion/Project/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/mnt/e/myProjects/LastVersion/Project/node_modules/sqlite3/
```